# Footer missing on form submission

Tags: php, forms, email, footer

Everything is fine on the form page themselves but the footer is missing on the echo after the forms are submitted. I am getting the emails and the header is there, the problem is just the footer. Here is the code for the entire page. There are two separate forms, one for join and one for edit info. Neither are not showing footers after forms are submitted.
Error log says

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';'

```
<?
include("config.php");
include("header.php"); 

if (!$_REQUEST['action']) { ?>

<h1>Join Form</h1>
<div align="justify">
<p>Fill out the form below to join this fanlisting. Please make sure     you've read the rules and if you have a website, that you put a link back up     to <?=$siteurl?> before joining!</p>
<p>Please note: <strong>this form is for joining only</strong>! If you wish to update your member information, please <a href="join.php?action=update">click here</a>.</p>

<script>
function submitonce(theform){
//if IE 4+ or NS 6+
if (document.all||document.getElementById){
//screen thru every element in the form, and hunt down "submit" and "reset"
for (i=0;i<theform.length;i++){
var tempobj=theform.elements[i]
if(tempobj.type.toLowerCase()=="submit"||tempobj.type.toLowerCase()=="reset")
//disable em
tempobj.disabled=true
}
}
}
</script>

<div align="center"><form method="post" action="join.php"         onSubmit="submitonce(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="apr" value="-">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="join">

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="90%">
<tr></tr><td width="30%">Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" size="40" class="form"></td>

</tr><tr><td>Email Address:<br>
<strong>Please Note</strong>: <em>All email addresses displayed on the member pages are proctected from SPAM by Javascript.</em></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" size="40" class="form"><br>
<input type="radio" name="hideemail" value="n" checked> Display My Email Address<br>
<input type="radio" name="hideemail" value="h"> Hide My Email Address</td>

</tr><tr><td>Website:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="url" value="" size="40" class="form"></td>

</tr><tr><td>Country:</td>
<td>
   <select name="country" class="form">
   <option value="0">Please choose:</option>
   <option value="0">___</option>
   <option value="USA">United States</option>
   <option value="England">England</option>
   <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
   <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
   <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
   <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
   <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
   <option value="0">___</option>
   <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
   <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
<option value="Antigua/Barbuda">Antigua/Barbuda</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
<option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Austria">Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize">Belize</option>
<option value="Benin">Benin</option>
<option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
<option value="Bosnia">Bosnia</option>
<option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
<option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
</select>
</td>

<? if ($enablefave == 'Y'){ ?>
</tr><tr><td class="small"><?=$whatfave?>:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fave" size="40" class="form"></td>
<? } ?>
</tr><tr><td>Any comments/questions?</td>
<td><textarea rows="3" name="comments" cols="40" class="form"></textarea>        </td>
</tr><tr colspan="2"><td><div align="center"><input type="submit" name="Subtmit Button" value="Join!" size="30" class="button"><input type="reset" name="Reset Button" value="Don't" size="30" class="button">        </div></td>
</tr></table></form></div>
<br>
<div align="center"><p>Powered by <a href="http://nothing-less.net/Nothing/you/script_fanbase.php" target="_blank">PHPFanBase</a> 2.0</p></div>

<? } elseif ($_POST['action'] == "join"){ 

if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) ||     !isset($_POST['country'])) {
header( "$siteurl/join.php" );
  } elseif (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||     empty($_POST['country'])) {

echo "<h2>Error</h2><p>Oops, it appears you forgot to enter either your email address, your name or your country. Please press the BACK button in your browser and try again.</P>"; 

} else {

$hideemail = $_POST['hideemail'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$fave = $_POST['fave'];
$apr = $_POST['apr'];

$query="SELECT id FROM $table WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$num=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num == "0"){

   if ($emailnotify == 'Y') {

$msg = "Name:\t$name\n";
$msg .= "E-Mail:\t$email\n";
$msg .= "Hide E-Mail:\t$hideemail\n";
$msg .= "URL:\t$url\n";
$msg .= "Country:\t$country\n";
if ($enablefave == 'Y') {
$msg .= "Fave:\t$fave\n";
}
$msg .= "Comments:\t$comments\n";
$msg .= "Sender IP:\t$REMOTE_ADDR\n";
$msg .= "\nLogin to your Admin Panel: $siteurl/admin.php\n";

$recipient = $adminemail;
$subject = "Member - $sitename";
$mailheaders = "From: $email\n";
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: $email\n\n";

 mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
 }

   if ($enablefave == 'Y') {
   $query = "INSERT INTO $table values       ('','$name','$email','$url','$country','$comments','$hideemail','$apr','$fave')";
   } else {
   $query = "INSERT INTO $table values     ('','$name','$email','$url','$country','$comments','$hideemail','$apr')";
 }
 mysqli_query($connect, $query);

echo "<p>Thank you, $_POST[name]! You will be added to the members list with the next update. :)</p>";

} else { ?>
<p>Sorry, but this email address is already listed in the database. This means that you're already listed as a member. If you wish to update your member information, please use the <a href="join.php?action=update">Update Form</a>. If you want to see your listing as a member, please <a href="members.php">click here</a>.</p> 
<? }
}

} elseif ($_GET['action'] == "update"){  ?>
<div align="justify">
<p>Please use the form below to update your member information. If you wish to join this fanlisting, use the Join Form located <a href="join.php">here</a>. Thanks!</p>

<script>
function submitonce(theform){
//if IE 4+ or NS 6+
if (document.all||document.getElementById){
//screen thru every element in the form, and hunt down "submit" and "reset"
for (i=0;i<theform.length;i++){
var tempobj=theform.elements[i]
    if(tempobj.type.toLowerCase()=="submit"||tempobj.type.toLowerCase()=="reset")
//disable em
tempobj.disabled=true
}
}
}
</script>

<div align="center"><form method="post" action="join.php" onSubmit="submitonce(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendupdate">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr><td>Member ID:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="id" size="40" class="form"></td>

</tr><tr><td>Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" size="40" class="form"></td>

</tr><tr><td>Old Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" size="40" class="form"></td>

</tr><tr><td>Old URL:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="url" value="http://" size="40" class="form">    </td>

</tr><tr><td>Country:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="country" size="40" class="form"></td>

</tr><tr><td>New Email:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="newemail" size="40" class="form"></td>

</tr><tr><td>New URL:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="newurl" value="http://" size="40" class="form"></td>

</tr><tr><td>Did anything else change?</td>
<td><textarea rows="3" name="comments" cols="40" class="form"></textarea>    </td>
</tr><tr colspan="2"><td><div align="center"><input type="submit" name="Subtmit Button" value="Send!" size="30" class="button"><input type="reset" name="Reset Button" value="Don't" size="30" class="button">    </div></td>
</tr></table></form></div>

<? } elseif ($_POST['action'] == "sendupdate"){  
if (!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) ||     !isset($_POST['country'])) {
header( "$siteurl/join.php?update" );
} elseif (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||     empty($_POST['country'])) {

echo "<h2>Error</h2><p>Oops, it appears you forgot to enter either your old email address, your name or your country. Please press the BACK button in your browser and try again.</P>";

} else {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$newemail = $_POST['newemail'];
$newurl = $_POST['newurl'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$fave = $_POST['fave'];
$apr = $_POST['apr'];

$msg = "Name:\t$name\n";
$msg .= "Old E-Mail:\t$email\n";
$msg .= "Old URL:\t$url\n";
$msg .= "Country:\t$country\n";
$msg .= "New E-Mail:\t$newemail\n";
$msg .= "New URL:\t$newurl\n";
$msg .= "Other Changes:\t$comments\n";
$msg .= "Sender IP:\t$REMOTE_ADDR\n";
$msg .= "\nLogin to your Admin Panel: $siteurl/admin.php\n";

$recipient = $adminemail;

$subject = "Update Info - $sitename";

$mailheaders = "From: $email\n";
$mailheaders .= "Reply-To: $email\n\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders); 
echo "<p>Thanks, your Update has been sent. I will change your information as     soon as possible!</p>";?>

<? } } include("footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: yes, script probably stops for some reason (check error log, or screen with `ErrorReporting(E_ALL)` )

Comment: You mean the footer.php file is  not being included?

Comment: error log saysPHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error before some `echo` in your code. 
Check in the error logs the line where it's breaking, or track it manually setting some prints or dumps.
You should try to write more readable code (indentation, not mixing that much html and php), because that is the main source of errors like this.

It says that expects ',' or ';', so maybe it's an unclosed array or function, or something like that. The code that you've posted does not show any static errors, so it's probably generated dinamically.

These, for example:

```
<? if ($enablefave == 'Y'){ ?>
// stuff
<? } elseif ($_POST['action'] == "join"){
```

That makes your code very hard to follow, thus very hard to track errors.
You have this syntax to do that:

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: the errors are on these lines... 313 `echo "<h2>Error</h2><p>Oops, it appears you forgot to enter either your email address, your name or your country. Please press the BACK button in your browser and try again.</P>"; ` 366 `<? } } }`421 `echo "<h2>Error</h2><p>Oops, it appears you forgot to enter either your old email address, your name or your country. Please press the BACK button in your browser and try again.</P>";` 453 `echo "<p>Thanks, your Update has been sent. I will change your information as soon as possible!</p>";?>`

Comment: Probably you left some empty tag in your **"$siteurl/join.php"** script.

Comment: Im not sure what that means

Comment: I mean, an error in the join.php script, that is generating an error in this script that you posted here. My advice is that you should try to refactor your code, for example, closing every block that you open before closing the php tags. I'm sure that these kind of errors will cease to appear.